# Specific pseudos and class styling not working properly

Tags: css

Why is this affecting a div with class icon-...  instead only the li as defined in css

```
 li [class*=" icon-"]{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
 }

<li class="something">
    <div class="insidediv icon-one">test</div>
</li>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="insidediv icon-one">test</div>
```

here is a sample
http://jsfiddle.net/65nkm/3/

only li with class  icon- ... should be affected but not a div inside an li

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space after `li` in your selector:

```
li[class*=" icon-"] {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 1.25em;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Check the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65nkm/7/).

Comment: No probs. For reference, `li [class]` matches any children of `li` that have a class beginning with `icon-`.